# Entity Framework Not Recognizing Different Schema in TableAttribute

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to update the Simple Authentication from the default MVC 4 Internet Application. My problem is my host provider appends a username as the schema of table I create, so instead of dbo.UserProfile I have a username.UserProfile table.

In the AccountModels.cs file I have updated the TableAttribute to be [Table("username.UserProfile")] instead of just [Table("UserProfile")] which should change the schema used according to this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute.aspx).

Though when running the application I still get an Entity Framework error.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.username.UserProfile'.

So it is still appending dbo as the schema... Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `[Table("UserProfile", Schema = "username")]` -- there's a separate property for the schema.

(I think you might've been getting tripped up from looking at the docs under the wrong namespace; the link you provided is for the `System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute` class, not the one in [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute.aspx).  How dare they use duplicate class names!!)